# Validate with joi strings array or object array

Tags: javascript

I need to find a way to validate array to be or strings array or object array of some schema bit not both.

This is what I did. Is there any other clean way?

```
Joi.object({
    barcodes: Joi.array()
        .min(1)
        .max(4)
        .items(Joi.alternatives().try(
            Joi.string(),
            taskInternalMetadataPayload,
        ).error(new Error(errorMessage)))
        .custom(checkArrayHasSameItemType)
        .unique()
        .unique('scannedLoadId')
        .messages({
            'array.unique': 'Scanned barcodes needs to be different',
        }),
})
```